# On Twilio how Can I see what the user is pressing during the IVR choice and send that choice to Zapier

Tags: twilio

On Twilio how Can I see what the user is pressing during the IVR choice and send that choice to Zapier.

I have a call line with a IVR that filters the calls. Based on the number chooses I would like to send that info to the appropriate person.

How can I see the selection and how can I send that to zapier ?

I try to connect the flow to Zapier but none of the option of the IVr appears.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you will need a webhook that receives the "action" from the [Gather](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather?code-sample=code-complex-gather-with-actionmethod-and-nested-say&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=6.x).

For example:

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();
var gather = new Gather(action: new Uri("/process_gather.php"),
             method: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Get);
           
gather.Say("Please enter your account number,\nfollowed by the pound sign");
        response.Append(gather);
        response.Say("We didn't receive any input. Goodbye!");

Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
```

In the above code, the "process_gather.php" will receive the Digits that the user presses. "The process_gather.php" will then call the Zapier webhook. Zapier will not "pull" or "poll" the digits from Twilio. You have to call the Zapier webhook to "push" the digits from Twilio into Zapier. Twilio will also expect that the "process_gather.php" endpoint will return Twiml to Twilio to tell it what to do next, or the call will end. Zapier may not be the right tool to use to build an IVR/routing application. [Twilio Studio Flow](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio) can do this out of the box and also trigger your Zapier webhook.